# how hibernate insert record in middle of table?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have a table of thousand records. I want to insert record in middle.The object I am saving in table is much complex. Which is convenient way to do this.

Comment: Can you explain it more, What's the middle mean and what the PK of your table?

Comment: What's 'the middle' of a database table? Usually, the order in your database doesn't matter. You can change the order when querying, or even in your Java application.

Comment: reference_tag_data_id is PK of my table @OQJF

Comment: And what doesn't the middle mean?

Comment: Middle means in between two records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the order of the data in the table is as of the order of the primary key of the table. Then, you can insert the record specifying the *primary key* in the pojo (setting the id eg: `employee.setId(25);`). But, if you do so you should not make the primary key as *auto_increment*.

Comment: We can not make Id as assigned we have to make it as native(auto_increment).We are saving new Objects Hibernate itself assigns ids.

Comment: @Rohit Kumar, then you are moving in an improper way. We should not bother about the order of the data in the table. We can take the data in any order (by applying some restrictions and all). Can you tell me what advantage you think by doing like this?

Comment: uid of ArticleData is in order. To insert in middle I will have to modify uid of each record. To do this I have to fetch all records lying after record I want to insert then modify uid and save records. This will take more time. I am looking for a solution which is time saving.